# How to use delete_vertices to remove, from a cluster_louvain, the group with the largest number of nodes?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

I'm using UKfaculty data available in the library igraphdata

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)
library(RColorBrewer)
data("UKfaculty")
```

I used the function `as.undirected()` to transform the directed graph to an undirected graph.

```
UND_UKfaculty <- as.undirected(UKfaculty)
```

And I applied the `cluster_louvain` function to get grouping:

```
lc <- cluster_louvain(UND_UKfaculty)
```

Now I found how many node I have in each group:

```
sizes(lc)
Community sizes
 1  2  3  4  5 
18 19 13 25  6
```

I am trying to remove from the initial graph the group with the highest number of nodes (group 4) with the function `delete_vertices`.

My question is focused on this last part. I don't get how to use the function `delete_vertices`.

I tried :

```
ld<-delete_vertices(lc, 4)
```

but it is mentioned that `delete_vertices(lc, 4)` is Not a graph object

Answer (score 0):

For the cluster id, e.g. 4, the corresponding vertices should be determined.
Then these vertices can be removed.
Note that the vertex ids in igraph are always automatically renumbered from 1 to max.
Therefore we have to preserve the vertex names of the source graph.

```
require(igraph)
##
## step 1
## calculate cluster, show in plot
## community object lc: vertices indexed by cluster id
g1 <- make_tree(20, children = 2, mode = "undirected")
V(g1)$names <- as.character(V(g1))
lc <- cluster_louvain(g1,  resolution = quantile(degree(g1))[4] / (ecount(g1) - 1))
plot(g1, mark.groups=lc)

## step2
## calculate the ids of the most densely populated clusters
## and determine the corresponding vertices
sz <- sizes(lc)
max_clusters <- ( which(sz == max(sz)) )
V_to_delete <- unlist(lc[max_clusters])

## step 3
## delete vertices and plot new graph
g2 <- delete_vertices(g1, V_to_delete)
V(g2)$label <- V(g2)$names
dev.new()
plot(g2)
```